# Transforming a dict to another structure in Python

Tags: python

I have a dict like below:

```
{'activity_count': [10, 11, 12], 'type': ['all', 'paper', 'fpy']}
```

I want to transform this dict into this form:

```
{'all': {'activity_count': 10}, 'paper': {'activity_count': 11}, 'fpy': {'activity_count': 12}}
```

How can I solve this?

So far I tried this solution,

```
dic={"activity_count":[10,11,12],"type":["all","paper","fpy"]}
in={}
i=0
for val in dic['type']:
    for v in dic['activity_count']:
        if i== dic['activity_count'].index(v):
            temp={}
            temp['activity_count']=v
            fin[val]=temp
    i+=1
```

It works as I expected, but it looks very ineffective way to achieve this task. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: `{type_: {'activity_count': count} for count, type_ in zip(dic['activity_count'], dic['type'])}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here a try, here `zip` is used to get values from both lists and to assign each:

```
d = {'activity_count': [10, 11, 12], 'type': ['all', 'paper', 'fpy']}
nd = {j:{'activity_count':i} for i, j in zip(d['activity_count'], d['type'])}
print(nd)
```

Comment: Instead of `zip(d['activity_count'], d['type'])` you can use `zip(*d.values())`.

Answer (score 6):

I would go for zip and dict comprehension:

```
test = {'activity_count': [10, 11, 12], 'type': ['all', 'paper', 'fpy']}
solution = {key:{'activity_count':value} for value, key in zip(test["activity_count"],test["type"])}
```

Explanation: The `zip` of your two list groups the elements of the two list by with identical index. So it will convert your lists to a generator where the values are like this: `[(10, 'all'), (11, 'paper'), (12, 'fpy')]`. But the generator is lazy evaluated, so the tuples are only processed, when the dict comprehension asks for them, this saves memory.

The dict comprehension just iterates over this generator and puts the second element as key and the first one as value.

Comment: Almost. Needs `key:{'activity_count':value}` rather than `key:value` to generate what was requested.

Comment: Oh yeah i was in rush, when i wrote the code. Thanks good catch, edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this dictionary comprehension using enumerate:

```
dictionary = {'activity_count': [10, 11, 12], 'type': ['all', 'paper', 'fpy']}
{e:{"activity_count":dictionary.get("activity_count")[c]} for c,e in enumerate(dictionary.get("type"))}
```